# php-amqplib: how to get the number of messages in prefetched cache?

Tags: rabbitmq, prefetch, php-amqplib

Related question:[Get queue size from rabbitmq consumer's callback with PhpAmqpLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685418/get-queue-size-from-rabbitmq-consumers-callback-with-phpamqplib/55686237#comment122405626_55686237)

In the above question the message count is obtained by `queue_declare`. However this message count only counts messages that are in the queue, but not the prefetched messages (which is exactly what the poster of that question is experiencing)

If I set the `prefetch_count` (in `basic_qos`) to 1 and send ack for every single message then the message count works perfectly, but if I set the `prefetch_count` to 10 and send ack for every 5 messages then the message count will be something like `100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, ...` when each message is handled.

What I want is to get the number of prefetched messages as well and add them up so that I will have the correct message count, including prefetched not but processed messages, when each message is handled.

Is there a way to obtain this number of cached messages in php-amqplib?

Comment: Glancing through [the API reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html) doesn't show anything relevant, so you might have to use [the HTTP API from the management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api).